# What is the best way to check if ALL values in a range exist in an array? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I have the task of determining whether each value from 1, 2, 3... n is in an unordered int array. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about this, but I created an int[] called range that just has all the numbers from 1-n in order at range[i] (range[0]=1, range[1]=2, ect). Then I tried to use the containsAll method to check if my array of given numbers contains all of the numbers in the range array. However, when I test this it returns false.  What's wrong with my code, and what would be a more efficient way to solve this problem?

```
public static boolean hasRange(int [] givenNums, int[] range) {
    boolean result = true;
    int n = range.length;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (Arrays.asList(givenNums).containsAll(Arrays.asList(range)) == false) {
           result = false;
     }
   }
    return result;
}
```

(I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to do this manually rather than using the containsAll method, so if anyone knows how to solve it that way it would be especially helpful!)

Here's where this method is implicated for anyone who is curious:

```
public static void checkMatrix(int[][] intMatrix) {
    File numberFile = new File("valid3x3") ;
    intMatrix= readMatrix(numberFile);
    int nSquared = sideLength * sideLength;
    int[] values = new int[nSquared];
    int[] range = new int[nSquared];
    int valCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<sideLength; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<sideLength; j++) {

            values[valCount] = intMatrix[i][j];
            valCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<range.length; i++) {
        range[i] = i+1;
    }

    Boolean valuesThere = hasRange(values, range);
```

valuesThere is false when printed.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` doesn't do what you expect when you pass to it a primitive array. It produces a List having a single member - the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a one dimensional array right?
Good. Then I think you are thinking to complicated.
I try to explain you another way to check if all numbers in an array are in number order.

For instance you have the array with following values:

```
int[] array = {9,4,6,7,8,1,2,3,5,8};
```

First of all you can order the Array simpel with

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

After you've done this you can loop through the array and compare with the index like (in a method):

```
for(int i = array[0];i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] != i) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to first sort the unsorted int array like you said then run a binary search to look for all values from 1...n. Sorry I'm not familiar with Java so I wrote in pseudocode. Instead of a linear search which takes O(N), binary search runs in O(logN) so is much quicker. But precondition is the array you are searching through must be sorted.

```
//pseudocode
int range[N] = {1...n};
cnt = 0;
while(i<-inputStream)
 int unsortedArray[cnt]=i
 cnt++;

sort(unsortedArray);

for(i from 0 to N-1)
{ 
  bool res = binarySearch(unsortedArray, range[i]);
  if(!res)
    return false;
 }
```

return true;

Answer (score 0):

What I comprehended from your description is that the array is not necessarily sorted (in order). So, we can try using `linear search` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean result = true;
    int[] range <- Contains all the numbers
    int[] givenNums <- Contains the numbers to check
    for(int i=0; i<givenNums.length; i++){
        if(!has(range, givenNums[i])){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result==false?"All elements do not exist":"All elements exist");
}

private static boolean has(int[] range, int n){
    //we do linear search here
    for(int i:range){
        if(i == n)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code displays whether all the elements in array `givenNums` exist in the array `range`.

Answer (score 0):

A mathematical approach: if you know the max value (or search the max value) check the sum. Because the sum for the numbers 1,2,3,...,n is always equal to n*(n+1)/2. So if the sum is equal to that expression all values are in your array and if not some values are missing. Example

```
public class NewClass12 {
   static int [] arr = {1,5,2,3,4,7,9,8};
   public static void main(String [] args){
      System.out.println(containsAllValues(arr, highestValue(arr)));
    }

    public static boolean containsAllValues(int[] arr, int n){        
       int sum = 0;        
       for(int k = 0; k<arr.length;k++){
          sum +=arr[k];
       }
       return (sum == n*(n+1)/2);
    }

   public static int highestValue(int[]arr){
       int highest = arr[0]; 
       for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           if(highest<arr[i]) highest = arr[i];
       }
       return highest;
     }
 }
```

according to this your method could look like this

```
public static boolen hasRange (int [] arr){
    int highest = arr[0];
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           if(highest<arr[i]) highest = arr[i];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k<arr.length;k++){
          sum +=arr[k];
    }
    return (sum == highest *(highest +1)/2);
}
```

Comment: This code will **ALWAYS** display `true` provided the formula is correct (idk). What you've done is passed an array and its max value, and are checking whether the sum of all its elements == `n*(n+1)/2` (let's put `2.0` instead of `2` to be safe). So what's the use of this code??

Comment: this code checks if all numbers from 1 upto n  are found in an int [] array. It does not return always true. For the given example it will return false since 6 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

First style:

```
if (condition == false) // Works, but at the end you have if (true == false) or such
if (!condition) // Better: not condition

// Do proper usage, if you have a parameter, do not read it in the method.
File numberFile = new File("valid3x3") ;
intMatrix = readMatrix(numberFile);
checkMatrix(intMatrix);

public static void checkMatrix(int[][] intMatrix) {
    int nSquared = sideLength * sideLength;
    int[] values = new int[nSquared];
```

Then the problem. It is laudable to see that a List or even better a Set approach is the exact abstraction level: going into detail not sensible. Here however just that is wanted.

To know whether every element in a range [1, ..., n] is present.

- You could walk through the given numbers,
- and for every number look whether it new in the range, mark it as no longer new,
- and if n new numbers are reached: return true.

  ```
  int newRangeNumbers = 0;
  boolean[] foundRangeNumbers = new boolean[n]; // Automatically false
  ```

Think of better names.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.asList(givenNums).
```

This does not do what you think.  It returns a `List<int[]>` with a single element, it does not box the values in `givenNums` to `Integer` and return a `List<Integer>`.  This explains why your approach does not work.

Using Java 8 streams, assuming you don't want to permanently sort `givens`. Eliminate the `copyOf()` if you don't care:

```
    int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(givens,givens.length);
    Arrays.sort(sorted);
    boolean result = Arrays.stream(range).allMatch(t -> Arrays.binarySearch(sorted, t) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean hasRange(int [] givenNums, int[] range) {
    Set result = new HashSet();

    for (int givenNum : givenNums) {
        result.add(givenNum);
    }

    for (int num : range) {
        result.add(num);
    }

    return result.size() == givenNums.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the function `hasRange` takes two primitive int array and when you pass primitive int array to `Arrays.asList` it will return a `List` containing a single element of type `int[]`. In this `containsAll` will not check actual elements rather it will compare primitive array object references.

Solution is either you create an `Integer[]` and then use `Arrays.asList` or if that's not possible then convert the `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

```
public static boolean hasRange(Integer[] givenNums, Integer[] range) {
    return Arrays.asList(givenNums).containsAll(Arrays.asList(range));
}
```

Check [here](http://ideone.com/aXV1vM) for sample code and output.

If you are using [ApacheCommonsLang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library you can directly convert `int[]` to `Integer[]`.
`Integer[] newRangeArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(range);`